# Как выводить HTTP статусы в SLIM

Tags: php, api, http, slim

есть такой код на SLIM, необходимо выводить HTTP статусы при ошибках. Не очень в этом разбираюсь. Направьте молодой ум.

```
$app->post('/products', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $next) use ($app) {
    global $mysql;
    $postJson = $request->getParsedBody();
    echo "$postJson[du]";
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tete`(`du`, `name`, `price`) VALUES ('$postJson[du]','$postJson[name]','$postJson[price]')";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query)) {
        echo "Все круто";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($mysql);
    }
    echo $response;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Тут не через `echo` нужно делать. Нужно примерно так:

```php
$app->post('/products', function (ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $next) use ($app) {
    global $mysql; // Это очень плохо, ищите про внедрение зависимостей
    $postJson = $request->getParsedBody();
    $body = $response->getBody();
    $body->write($postJson["du"]);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tete`(`du`, `name`, `price`) VALUES ('$postJson[du]','$postJson[name]','$postJson[price]')";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysql, $query)) {
        $body->write("Всё круто");
        return $response;
    } else {
        $body->write(mysqli_error($mysql));
        return $response->withStatusCode(500);
    }
    return $response;
});
```